# MotionLayout OnSwipe touchRegionId clashes with OnClick targetId

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I have this transition in my MotionLayout.

```xml
<Transition
    android:id="@+id/transition_validate"
    motion:constraintSetEnd="@id/endRight"
    motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
    motion:duration="400"
    motion:motionInterpolator="easeOut">
  <OnClick
      motion:clickAction="transitionToEnd"
      motion:targetId="@id/trueButton" />
  <OnSwipe
      motion:dragDirection="dragRight"
      motion:touchAnchorId="@id/card"
      motion:touchRegionId="@id/card"
      motion:touchAnchorSide="right" />
```

the rectangle in the middle is the cardView with `card` as id.
the buttons left and right of the screen are trueButton/falseButton

My problem is that after I added `motion:touchRegionId="@id/card"` to onSwipe, I can't no longer clic on **1**, ie the part of `trueButton` that is above `card` to launch the animation (it's actually on false instead of true on the screen attached but you get the idea), I have to clic on 3 ie, the part of `trueButton` that is not above the card.

[image]

Have you ever seen something like that ? Do you know how can I restrain onSwipe to `card` touches but have clicks on the buttons launch the animations ?

Thanks